# Two circles each of which passes through the centre of the other intersect points M and N.

Tags: circles

[image: Question]

**Two circles each of which passes through the centre of the other intersect points M and N. A line from M intersects the circle at K and L as shown in the figure. If KL = 6 compute the area of ∆KLN.**

I was attempting a Practice Paper and stumbled on this Question.

I think the tangent secant theorem must used somewhere which states that.

$Tangent^2=Outer Secant×Whole Secant$

But I don't know where to apply it so I am clueless.

I don't know where to start from.

*Any help will be appreciated*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Realize that $\angle NKM= 120^o$ and that $\angle KLN= 60^o$, which leaves $\Delta KLN$ an equilateral triangle. The answer is therefore $9\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Here is link for the basic angle theorems in a circle: https://mathbitsnotebook.com/Geometry/Circles/CRAngles.html

Comment: How did you find the aswer to be 9√3?

Comment: How did you find angle NKM to be 120°? I've gone through the links but none of the theorems help me find the angle.

Comment: I added another image as a hint. You already know that $\angle KLN= 60^o$, so according to the theorem I just added, $\angle KLN = 180^o - \angle KLN= 180^o- 60^o=120^o$. And the area of an equilateral triangle can be calculated if you know one side of the triangle.

Comment: $\angle NOM=\angle NKM$ since these two angles are on the same intercepted arc.